# Excel VBA code to transfer data on the last empty row on google sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to transfer data from excel to google sheet through VBA Userform, this user form is used to update the orders inventory.i have on list box in this form witch allow user to add multiple Items on one order request. My code is trnfering data in google sheet, but i am facing only one issue, I am not able to get last used row to insert data in google sheet. currently my data is transfer to random rows. Please let me know how to fix this problem.
my cod is s below:

```
`With Inventoryform

phone = .Textphonenumber
lastname = .Textlastname
name = .TextfirstName
email = .Textemail
time = .Textcontacttime
add1 = .Textaddress1
add2 = .Textaddress2
add3 = .Textaddress3
city = .Textcity
state = .Textstate
zip = .Textzip
country = .Textcountry

For p = 1 To .ListBox1.ListCount - 1

pname = .ListBox1.List(p, 0)
pclass = .ListBox1.List(p, 1)
pdiscreption = .ListBox1.List(p, 2)
serial = .ListBox1.List(p, 3)
store = .ListBox1.List(p, 4)
qty = .ListBox1.List(p, 5)
price = .ListBox1.List(p, 6)

xmlHTTPHeader = "content-type"
xmlID = "application/x-www.form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8"
URL_first = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe1_FVJjoFUW_SKYr0ttKK_a5FBLPMWgGCvEKNFAXV4T_RJNg/formResponse?ifq"
URL_seccond = "&entry.402760373=" & name & "&entry.8402683=" & lastname & "&entry.2013589844=" & phone & "&entry.952452731=" & time & " &entry.48164907= " & email & " &entry.1356643996=" & zip & "&entry.2002379396=" & add1 & "&entry.1231724023=" & add2 & " &entry.421644231=" & add3 & " &entry.1747336923=" & city & " &entry.1613048973=" & state & " &entry.875063098=" & country & " &entry.319273916=" & pname & "&entry.158999870=" & pclass & "&entry.1321582544=" & pdiscreption & "&entry.418874757=" & serial & "&entry.1230323140=" & store & "&entry.2123202381=" & price & "&entry.1785381471=" & qty & "&submit=Submit"
googlesheeturl = URL_first & URL_seccond
Set xmlHTTP = New ServerXMLHTTP60
xmlHTTP.Open "post", googlesheeturl, False
xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader xmlHTTPHeader, xmlID
xmlHTTP.send


Next p`
```

Comment: I realize this doesn't answer your question, but using Excel as a userform is probably not the best approach. Google and MS have products literally called `forms` that will auto-populate spreadsheets as users provide information.

Comment: When you say your data is being transferred to random rows, is the new data overwriting the whole existing row - never going to the last row? Have you made any changes to columns or data on the Form Response sheet?

Comment: @dbmitch Many Thanks for your response, The data is not going to the Last Blank row, and it is not overwriting on the existing data also. let say if I have data available on row 3 and I run this code again the new data will be transferred to row 45.

Comment: It looks like you are posting to a google form and not directly to a sheet. It may be easier to go straight to the sheet. This [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) may help.

Comment: @FreelancingTech - can you select the entire dataset, filter the rows by blank first column field (clear then select Blanks), select all of the rows using shift key and then right click to Delete Rows. See if that resets the internal counter for used rows